Naming the philosophy of disengagement
What is the name of philosophical current, suggest that political, social, and economics events are largely beyond our control, and therefore there is no point stressing about these things, engaging in debates, participating in protests, voting, etc.
There is probably more than one such current: I tend to associate it with Absurdism, but this seems to put accent on the irrationality of events and the individual reasons for living. These are not necessarily the features in the description I gave in the first paragraph - the events might well be happening for a reason, but beyond our control. One also may be quite clear about the one's reasons for living, but still do not believe that they can influence the world beyond their family/workplace/circle of friends. Individualism is another option, but again I do not think that individualists believe that influencing the world is beyond their capacity (though they do watch for their interests).

The name is political fatalism, "understood as a commitment to the belief that human agency cannot effectuate social transformation", see Slothuus. However, its premise borders on being factually false and makes it unpopular. But there is a more defensible form of favoring disengagement without the fatalistic thesis, political quietism, "quietist may still value these things, yet at the same time have other values which serve to assuage the temptation to indulge in them."

@Conifold thank you - this seems very close to what I was looking for.

The article under the link is informative. Ironically, I was going to incorporate the term "political fatalism" into my answer. In my lexicon all human social relations are political relations. Some professional economists argue that economics is a distinct discipline from politics. But, of course, this is a political argument!

Fatalism broadly interpreted incorporates the idea that one cannot change the course of natural or social events.
SEP - Fatalism
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fatalism/

Though the word “fatalism” is commonly used to refer to an attitude of resignation in the face of some future event or events which are thought to be inevitable, philosophers usually use the word to refer to the view that we are powerless to do anything other than what we actually do. This view may be argued for in various ways: by appeal to logical laws and metaphysical necessities; by appeal to the existence and nature of God; by appeal to causal determinism. When argued for in the first way, it is commonly called “Logical fatalism” (or, in some cases, “Metaphysical fatalism”); when argued for in the second way, it is commonly called “Theological fatalism”. When argued for in the third way it is not now commonly referred to as “fatalism” at all, and such arguments will not be discussed here.

The article recognizes determinism as a form of fatalism. The idea that all events are generated as random outcomes would also be a form of fatalism.
I don't know if there is a specific word or term for social fatalism. Psychotherapy models have many subjective terms that apply primarily to patterns of social engagement or disengagement. The conviction that one's actions as an agent are not effective in the social world could also map broadly to psychological theories incorporating concepts of blame, powerlessness, helplessness, and/or learned helplessness. By contrast, US dropout culture, or the Chinese theme of lying flat, can also be seen as autonomous choice defying the social pressures to conform to some cultural norm.
